# Can I develop multi tenancy application by using RabbitMQ and spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I want to implement multi tenancy application by using RabbitMQ and Spring Boot in my current project. Currently the application is running in a single tenant manner. The approach is to create separate virtual host  per tenant. The issue we are facing is how to read messages from different different virtual hosts in the single spring boot application.

We are using spring boot spring-boot-starter-amqp.

Could you please let me know if this can be done (and if so how)? Any high level code would be useful?

Answer (score 1):

Here `configTemplateRabbitMQ` is nothing but an object which contains the username, password and address.

By using `cachingConnectionFactory` you can set all the properties.

You can pass the information dynamically.

#### pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Code

```
public void publish(String message, ConfigTemplateRabbitMQ configTemplateRabbitMQ) {
        logger.info("publishing message: {}", message);

        if (message != null) {
            CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();

            connectionFactory.setUsername(configTemplateRabbitMQ.getUsername());
            connectionFactory.setPassword(configTemplateRabbitMQ.getPassword());
            connectionFactory.setAddresses(configTemplateRabbitMQ.getAddresses());

            AmqpTemplate dynamicRabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);

            dynamicRabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(configTemplateRabbitMQ.getExchangeName(), configTemplateRabbitMQ.getPrefix(), message);
        }
        else
            logger.error("message is empty!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare multiple connection factories with corresponding `AmqpAdmin`s. After declaring `AmqpAdmin`s you can bind them to exchanges / queues you use.

Here is some sample `@Configuration` class code declaring two exchanges on two different virtual hosts.

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory firstVhostConnectionFactory(final RabbitProperties properties, @Value("${application.vhost1}") String firstVhostName) {
        var connFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connFactory.setHost(properties.getHost());
        connFactory.setPort(properties.getPort());
        connFactory.setUsername(properties.getUsername());
        connFactory.setPassword(properties.getPassword());
        connFactory.setVirtualHost(firstVhostName);

        return connFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    ConnectionFactory secondVhostConnectionFactory(final RabbitProperties properties, @Value("${application.vhost2}") String secondVhostName) {
        var connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connFactory.setHost(properties.getHost());
        connFactory.setPort(properties.getPort());
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(secondVhostName);
        connFactory.setUsername(properties.getUsername());
        connFactory.setPassword(properties.getPassword());

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    AmqpAdmin firstVhostAdmin() {
        var admin = new RabbitAdmin(firstVhostConnectionFactory());
        admin.afterPropertiesSet();
        return admin;
    }

    @Bean
    AmqpAdmin secondVhostAdmin() {
        var admin = new RabbitAdmin(secondVhostConnectionFactory());
        admin.afterPropertiesSet();
        return admin;
    }

    @Bean
    FanoutExchange orderStatusRequestExchange() {
        var exchange = new FanoutExchange("secondVhostExchange", true, false);

        // This exchange will be declared on first vhost
        exchange.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(firstVhostAdmin());
        return exchange;
    }

    @Bean
    FanoutExchange secondVhostExchange() {
        var exchange = new FanoutExchange("secondVhostExchange", true, false);

        // This exchange will be declared on second vhost
        exchange.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(secondVhostAdmin());
        return exchange;
    }

    @Bean
    Queue orderStatusRequestExchange() {
        var exchange = new FanoutExchange("secondVhostExchange", true, false);

        // This exchange will be declared on first vhost
        exchange.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(firstVhostAdmin());
        return exchange;
    }

    @Bean
    Queue secondVhostExchange() {
        var exchange = new FanoutExchange("secondVhostExchange", true, false);

        // This exchange will be declared on second vhost
        exchange.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(secondVhostAdmin());
        return exchange;
    }

    @Bean
    Queue firstVhostQueue() {
        var queue = new AnonymousQueue();
        queue.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(firstVhostAdmin());
        return queue;
    }


    @Bean
    Queue secondVhostQueue() {
        var queue = new AnonymousQueue();
        queue.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(secondVhostAdmin());
        return queue;
    }

    @Bean
    Binding firstVhostBinding(FanoutExchange firstVhostExchange, Queue firstVhostQueue) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(firstVhostQueue).to(firstVhostExchange);
    }


    @Bean
    Binding secondVhostBinding(FanoutExchange secondVhostExchange, Queue secondVhostQueue) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(secondVhostQueue).to(secondVhostExchange);
    }
}
```

After that, you can use declared queues in your `@RabbitListener`s and fetch data from both vhosts.

Answer (score 0):

Boot auto configuration can only configure one connection factory.

You need to register the infrastructure beans (connection factories, templates, container factories) yourself.